# Spring Boot jar ignores application.properties

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I made jar from intellij, after running it i see that hickari ignores my properties, because the link in there is

> 18:44:03.750 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

but in my properties i have

> jdbc:h2:mem:tempdb;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SEMANTIC;

Is there an extra step so that jar uses the application.properties?

Comment: *"I made jar from intellij"* You should have your Maven/Gradle build script do that, not IntelliJ, assuming you correctly wrote the build script according to Spring Boot instructions, because that would ensure that the build script knows how to do it correctly.

Comment: where do i get this build script? i tried to mvn clean install. But was getting errors there

Comment: [Getting Started | Building an Application with Spring Boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)